# Unable to access to created graph on AgensGraph

Tags: agens-graph

Unalbe to access on graph after re-login.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 1.3, based on PostgreSQL 10.3)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# create graph graph;
CREATE GRAPH
agens=# match (n) return n;
 n 
---
(0 rows)

agens=# \q
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 1.3, based on PostgreSQL 10.3)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
ERROR:  graph_path is NULL
HINT:  Use SET graph_path
agens=# \q
```

How can I access to created graph?

How can I call "set graph_path" on login automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use "set graph_path" command for search on your graph.

```
agens (AgensGraph 1.3, based on PostgreSQL 10.3)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# set graph_path to graph;
SET
agens=# match (n) return n;
 n 
---
(0 rows)

agens=# \q
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 1.3, based on PostgreSQL 10.3)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
ERROR:  graph_path is NULL
HINT:  Use SET graph_path
agens=# \q
```

But, You must set graph_path everytime on login.

For avoid inconvenience, You can set graph_path on your account.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 1.3, based on PostgreSQL 10.3)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# alter user agens set graph_path to graph;
ALTER ROLE
agens=# \q
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 1.3, based on PostgreSQL 10.3)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
 n 
---
(0 rows)

agens=# \q
```

Use "alter user" for set graph_path of user.